# groovy extract value from string

Tags: groovy

I got a string from a server response:

```
responseString:"{"session":"vvSbMInXHRJuZQ==","age":7200,"prid":"901Vjmx9qenYKw","userid":"user_1"}"
```

then I do:

```
responseString[1..-2].tokenize(',')
```

got:

```
[""session":"vvSbMInXHRJuZQ=="", ""age":7200", ""prid":"901Vjmx9qenYKw"", ""userid":"user_1""]
```

get(3)  got:

```
""userid":"user_1""
```

what I need is the user_1, is there anyway I can actually get it? I have been stuck here, other json methods get similar result, how to remove the outside ""?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code can help you get you to the userid.

```
def str= 'responseString:"{:"session":"vvSbMInXHRJuZQ==","age":7200,"prid":"901Vjmx9qenYKw","userid":"user_1","hdkshfsd":"sdfsdfsdf"}'
def match = (str=~ /"userid":"(.*?)"/)
log.info match[0][1]
```

this pattern can help you getting any of the values you want from the string. Try replacing userid with age, you will get that

```
def match = (str=~ /"age":"(.*?)"/)
```

@Michael code is also correct. Its just that you have clarified that you want the user Name to be specific

Comment: This will not work, if the user name contains `"` itself. (E.g. '..."user\"name"...')

Comment: Chances are rare that Quote within Quote, yes but if its there then we may have to modify pattern

Answer (score 2):

If you pull out the proper JSON from `responseStr`, then you can use `JsonSlurper`, as shown below:

```
def s = 'responseString:"{"session":"vvSbMInXHRJuZQ==","age":7200,"prid":"901Vjmx9qenYKw","userid":"user_1"}"'

def matcher = (s =~ /responseString:"(.*)"/)
assert matcher.matches()
def responseStr = matcher[0][1]

import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def json = jsonSlurper.parseText(responseStr)
assert "user_1" ==  json.userid
```

Comment: what the response is actually only: "{"session":"vvSbMInXHRJuZQ==","age":7200,"prid":"901Vjmx9qenYKw","userid":"user_1"}" . thank you.